# Loud Noise on Encrypted Voice Chat in Java Through UDP

Tags: java, encryption, udp, chat, voice

We had to built a encrypted/decrypted voice chat through UDP. Chat is working without encryption but when I add AES code to encrypt, i hear very loud noise which is continuous periodic beep signal but at the same time I also hear decrypted conversations which is fine. I need to eliminate this noise.

We will be so grateful for your help. Thank you

Sending

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class MicPlayer {

private static final String IP_TO_STREAM_TO   = "localhost" ;
private static final int PORT_TO_STREAM_TO     = 1234 ;

/** Creates a new instance of MicPlayer */
public MicPlayer() {

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
Mixer.Info minfo[] = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo() ;
for( int i = 0 ; i < minfo.length ; i++ )
{
 System.out.println( minfo[i] ) ;    
}


if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)) {
try {


  DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info( TargetDataLine.class , getAudioFormat() ) ;
  TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine( dataLineInfo  ) ;
  targetDataLine.open( getAudioFormat() );
  targetDataLine.start();
  byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[8192] ;

  while( true )
  {
  targetDataLine.read( tempBuffer , 0 , tempBuffer.length );
  byte[] encrypt = AES.encrypt(tempBuffer);
  sendThruUDP(encrypt) ;

  }

}
catch(Exception e )
{
System.out.println(" not correct " ) ;
System.exit(0) ;
}
}



}


public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
//8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
//8,16
int channels = 1;
//1,2
boolean signed = true;
//true,false
boolean bigEndian = false;
//true,false
return new AudioFormat( sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian );
}


public static void sendThruUDP( byte soundpacket[] )
{
   try
   {
   DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket() ; 
   sock.send( new DatagramPacket( soundpacket , soundpacket.length , InetAddress.getByName( IP_TO_STREAM_TO ) , PORT_TO_STREAM_TO ) ) ; 
   sock.close() ;
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
   e.printStackTrace() ;
   System.out.println(" Unable to send soundpacket using UDP " ) ;   
   }

}



}
```

Receiving

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

public class RadioReceiver extends Thread {

private static final String IP_TO_STREAM_TO   = "localhost" ;
private static final int PORT_TO_STREAM_TO     = 1234;

/** Creates a new instance of RadioReceiver */
public RadioReceiver() {
}

public void run()
{
    byte b[] = null ;
    while( true )
    {
       b = receiveThruUDP() ; 
       toSpeaker( b ) ;
    }        
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

RadioReceiver r = new RadioReceiver() ;
r.start() ;

}


public static byte[] receiveThruUDP()
{
   try
   {
   DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(PORT_TO_STREAM_TO) ; 
   byte soundpacket[] = new byte[8192] ;
   DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket( soundpacket , soundpacket.length , InetAddress.getByName( IP_TO_STREAM_TO ) , PORT_TO_STREAM_TO ) ;
   sock.receive( datagram ) ; 
   sock.close() ;
   return AES.decrypt(datagram.getData()); // soundpacket ;
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
   System.out.println(" Unable to send soundpacket using UDP " ) ;   
   return null ;
   } 

}


 public static void toSpeaker( byte soundbytes[] )
 {

  try{  
  DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info( SourceDataLine.class , getAudioFormat() ) ;
  SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine( dataLineInfo );
  sourceDataLine.open( getAudioFormat() ) ;
  sourceDataLine.start();

  sourceDataLine.write( soundbytes , 0, soundbytes.length );
  sourceDataLine.drain() ;
  sourceDataLine.close() ;
  }
  catch(Exception e )
  {
  System.out.println("not working in speakers " ) ;
  }

}


public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
{
float sampleRate = 44100.0F;
//8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
//8,16
int channels = 1;
//1,2
boolean signed = true;
//true,false
boolean bigEndian = false;
//true,false
return new AudioFormat( sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian );
}



}
```

AES

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {
static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
static String encryptionKey = "0123456789abcdef";

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] inputcum) throws Exception {
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
return cipher.doFinal(inputcum);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherSound) throws Exception{
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
return cipher.doFinal(cipherSound);
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is not related to UDP or encryption. You are ignoring the return value of `targetDataLine.read( tempBuffer , 0 , tempBuffer.length )`. I am pretty sure that most of the time it reads less than the buffer size, with remaining data being garbage from previous calls.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Post an answer and we can up-vote and take this off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to UDP or encryption. Each call to `TargetDataLine.read(byte[])` fills only a part of array with remaining part being filled with leftovers from the previous calls, but you are encrypting and sending the whole array each time.

A call to [TargetDataLine.read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/TargetDataLine.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) behaves similar to [InputStream.read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) - it returns the actual number of bytes transferred into the byte array. This value must not be ignored.

For the minimum working process the code should be modified along the following guidelines:

When sending:

```
while( true ) {
    int read = targetDataLine.read( tempBuffer , 0 , tempBuffer.length );
    byte[] encrypt = AES.encrypt(tempBuffer, 0, read);
    sendThruUDP(encrypt) ;
}
```

When encrypting (notice that the padding is changed to `PKCS5Padding` to allow for input length which is not a multiple of the AES block size):

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainData, int offset, int length) throws Exception 
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return cipher.doFinal(plainData, offset, length);
}
```

The `decrypt()` method should be modified to use the same padding.

Other most obvious improvements:

- Generate new random IV for each data block and send a packet that contains both the IV and the encrypted data. It will require some copying between a number of byte arrays both on the sending+encrypting and receiving+decrypting side, but **reusing the same IV for multiple cipher operations on the same key is absolutely unsafe** from the cryptography point of view.
- Use the proper key derivation function (search for PBKDF2) instead of simply converting a password string to bytes.
- Get an instance of `Cipher` once and then just reinitialize it with the key and a new IV. That will save a bit of CPU and memory.

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Estekhin said "The problem is not related to UDP or encryption. You are ignoring the return value of targetDataLine.read( tempBuffer , 0 , tempBuffer.length ). I am pretty sure that most of the time it reads less than the buffer size, with remaining data being garbage from previous calls"
 I agree and use a *CTR* or *GCM* as a mode of operation **not** CBC because CBC is slower.